# How can I put location in "Battery Saving" mode in Android Pie?

Tags: battery-life, geolocation, 9.0-pie, location-services

In Android Oreo, when location was on, there were 3 choices for how it worked: Device Only, Battery Saving, or High Accuracy. In Pie, it's easy to change to Device Only or High Accuracy by turning "Google Location Accuracy" on or off in Location settings. How can I change to Battery Saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has removed all of the UI from the OS to change this setting, but it's still changeable in other ways.

If an app has the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission, it can do this by calling `Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING);`. [The Tiles app in the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rascarlo.quick.settings.tiles) includes a Location tile that does exactly this.

Alternatively, if you have ADB or root, you can do this with no third-party apps by running `settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network,-gps` from an ADB shell or a root shell.

Comment: `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission is not for use by third-party applications https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Comment: @Jim yes, but there's a workaround via adb to grant it to them anyway.

Comment: thanks~ i'll try, btw after `putInt(LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING)` how can i use back to high accuracy mode? can i simply change it to `LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY`?